# how to read jquery ajax returned object with out a loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, object

Given the following jquery ajax request:

```
$.getJSON("getSearchSystems.php", {level: "full", data:this.label}, function(data){
     //This method does not work.
     console.log(data.regionName);
     console.log(data.constellationName);
     console.log(data.solarSystemName);

     //This method does work
     $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
        console.log(elem.regionName);
        console.log(elem.constellationName);
        console.log(elem.solarSystemName);
    });

});
```

Output:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
The Bleak Lands
Sasen
Kuomi
```

JSON response from PHP script

```
[{"regionName":"The Bleak Lands","constellationName":"Sasen","solarSystemName":"Kuomi"}]
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to access this objects data with out iterating over it.  Is there not a way to do this without a loop?

I would like to be able to access the data like `var regionName = data.regionName`

Comment: Show us the JSON returned by the ajax request. What's wrong with using a loop?

Comment: try `console.log(data[0].regionName);
`

Comment: @Matt Ball Sorry for the late response, had to run to dinner

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` print?

Comment: @3nigma Can you put this in an answer so I can give you credit for it.  This worked like a charm.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 console.log(data[0].regionName);
```

just dont ask why but some times the data is returned as array and is to be accessed like `data[0]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop your server needs to send an array, like this:

```
[ { regionName: 'r1', constellationName: 'c1', solarSystemName: 's1' }, 
  { regionName: 'r2', constellationName: 'c2', solarSystemName: 's2' } ]
```

Looking at those `undefined` values that your are getting I suspect that the first element of this array doesn't contain any `regionName`, `constellationName` and `solarSystemName` properties and it looks something like this:

```
[ { someIrrelevantProperty: 'foo bar', someOtherirrelevantProperty: 'baz' }, 
  { regionName: 'The Bleak Lands', constellationName: 'Sasen', solarSystemName: 'Kuomi' } ]
```

Comment: I apologize for not posting the JSON dump, but the fact that loop works and the with out it doesn't completely invalidates your answer.  How would I get the response I get from the loop if the `regionName`,`constellationName`, and `solarSystemName` where not in fact the first values?

Comment: @We, use FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools to inspect the returned JSON from the server.

Comment: i had to use data[0].regionName for it to work.  I am just waiting for the poster that put it as a suggestion to put it in an answer so that can mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

Does your request always return json object array like your json dump?

If so, you always get undefined when you call `console.log(data.regionName);` without iteration since your raw data is an array and you try to reference json array's undefined property.

However, if you are trying to check for a specific value like error checking value, results count, or some other value relevant with your business; you have to response with an object that contains your data array among with the other values you needed. Like this;

```
{"object1":"value1", "object2":[{"regionName":"The Bleak Lands","constellationName":"Sasen","solarSystemName":"Kuomi"}]}
```

Comment: The jquery automatically puts the JSON response into a JSON object.

Comment: Yes it always returns json as I use phps json_encode() to encode the array/objects before i send them to javascript